# Sanity check on Binomial Distribution

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

I ran following in R Studio:

> dbinom(10, size=20, prob=0.6)
>   [1] 0.1171416
>
> dbinom(10, size=30, prob=0.6)
>   [1] 0.001997491
>
> And this seems counter-intuitive to me.  If the number of trials increases, and the probability of each event remains constant, shouldn't the probability of observing 10 successes increase when the number of trials goes up?

Comment: You ar looking at the probability of *exactly* $10$ successes, not *at least*, and you expect $12$ successes in the former case compared with $18$ in the latter.  It is not very different to saying `dnorm(10, mean=12, sd=2.191)` would give you a much bigger value than `dnorm(10, mean=18, sd=2.683)`.  In the former case you are about $1$ standard deviation away from the mean while in the latter you are about $3$ standard deviations away; in addition the probability is more concentrated in the former distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - remember that your use of the dbinom function returns the probability of observing *exactly* 10 successes. With a larger sample space (30 vs 20) the probability of that exact occurrence actually becomes less likely. If you employ the cumulative distribution function (pbinom) you’ll find that the probability of encountering 10 *or more* successes increases from 20 trials to 30 trials (but note you need to do a 1-p correction as pbinom gives p(X<=x)

Comment: Thank you.  I got turned around on the dbinom returning the probability of an exact number of events.  that makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your intuition fails if you think of observing something like *at least 10 successes*, then in fact the larger the sample, the probability will be grater. But you ask about observing *exactly 10 successes*. Think of more extreme case, say 10 000 000 trials, would observing *exactly 10 successes* (probability mass function), or *not more then 10 successes* (cumulative distribution function) be "likely" in such setting?